# Error 403 Forbidden |localhost | in Ubuntu i do not come enter to index.php

Tags: 14.04, php, apache2.4

I have this project in PHP. The whole project is fine except when I browse to index.php on localhost, it me sends this error?

[image: Forbidden Error]

Comment: check file permissions for every folder/file in your project

Comment: Does this happen only for this site, or for any page you try to put up? It sounds like your setup might be for apache2.2 and not updated to 2.4 yet, meaning that its config files or settings in apache might not have the right syntax, like `Require all granted` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a permissions error. Try `sudo chmod -R 775` on the directory in question. (Preferably where the site's `root` folder is).

As well, use `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` to open nano and enter this at the bottom of the file (keep in mind that [folder name] is your root folder for the site.

> `<Directory [folder name]>
>   AllowOverride All
>   </Directory>`

Answer (score 1):

I would check permissions, but also your configuration settings in apache.

There were a couple changes in how to allow permissions to your directory or project, which if the project was started under apache2.2 it would take some updating.

[Apache Upgrade Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html)

To sum up one of the big gotchas: (quoted from linked site, emphasis added)

Here are some examples of old and new ways to do the same access control.

*In this example, there is no authentication and all requests are denied.*

**2.2 configuration:**

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

**2.4 configuration:**

> Require all denied

*In this example, there is no authentication and all requests are allowed.*

**2.2 configuration:**

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

**2.4 configuration:**

> Require all granted

Check those out as well as your directory permissions (making sure your web server user can access all directories in the path to this folder).